# Getting Error during migration generation: Error: Cannot find module 'src/account/account.entity'

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

So I am doing typeorm relations on two entities; Users and Shows
I am doing a one-to-one relation on Shows as:

`@OneToOne(() => Users) @JoinColumn() creators: Users;`

However, if I run typeorm's `migration:generate` , i get this error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VefjL.jpg

Any idea on what's happening?

I was expecting to generate a new migration successfully with the `migration:generate` command.